# How can I predict a distribution (from a set of predictors) that I can simulate from?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, simulation, quantile-regression

Let's say I have the following regression problem:

Given a person's age and height, I want to predict how many years they've spent playing basketball. However, instead of just regressing on these features, I'd like to actually predict a distribution that I can simulate from: for each sample, I'd like to predict a distribution (for instance, predict the parameters for the normal distribution) for each specific test sample, that I can then draw samples from to simulate on.

More explicit example: after training my model, if I have a test sample with [age=25, height=72"], I'd like to predict the distribution for how many years that person has spent playing basketball, so I can draw samples from that predicted distribution for simulation purposes. Seems similar to quantile regression but I'd like to predict an explicit distribution that I can sample from...

Any tips for how to go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with linear regression! Whether you use the MLE or minimize the mean squared error, you are actually modeling the *mean* response, conditional on the predictors, and you are implicitly assuming that the response itself is normally distributed around that mean. For other distributions, you would use a generalized linear model.

What you're looking for also arises naturally as the "posterior predictive distribution" in a Bayesian model. It might be helpful to think of maximum-likelihood-based inference as Bayesian inference with flat priors.

Fully nonparametric density estimation is very difficult in general except in low-dimensional cases. I asked an involved question about it about a year ago, but I can't find it now.

Comment: awesome, thank you! for linear regression, would I just use the minimized MSE across the training set to find sigma for the normal distribution? or is there a more clever way to figure this out?

Comment: @defcal almost. It's the sum of squared errors divided by $n-2$ (rather than just $n$).